# Trying to groupby two columns in pandas and return a max value based on criteria

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, group-by

I need some help with a dataset that I am trying to perform a `.groupby()` on to find the `.max()` `consumption` value based on `Entity` and `Year`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AvVh.png)import

The `consumption` column that I am using to perform the max function, sometimes has the same value for different `Year`s. When this occurs I would like to return the `max` `Year` for that occurrence.

`df.groupby(['Entity','Year']).consumption.max().reset_index()`

returns

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLnEn.png)

In the end I would like a `DataFrame` with `['Entity','Year','consumption']` as the columns and when the `consumption` is the same for a specific  `Entity` `Year` pair, to return the highest `Year` of the two.

Answer (score 0):

I worked up a solution

```
df4 = df.groupby('Entity').consumption.max().reset_index()
df5 = df4.merge(df, left_on=['Entity', 'consumption'] , right_on=['Entity', 'consumption'])
df5 = df5.groupby(['Entity', 'consumption']).max().reset_index()
df5.head(10)
```

[Unique Countries with max consumption rates, and if the consumption rate was the same year-over-year, return the max year.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muFWg.png)